# OpenGL ES 2.0 / iOS: Skewed drawing of RGBA4 texture

Tags: ios, opengl-es, xamarin.ios, opengl-es-2.0

I'm loading my textures with a working DDS loader but there seems to be an issue with the RGBA4 format ( GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4 ) which is drawn skewed.
I'm using the same shader on the background ( which is working but uses RGB565 ) and the other texture.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Fail Rendering]

As you can see the texture is skewed, it should be a back button.
The texture loading is correct too, it loads all bytes it should load ( debugged this ) and the OpenGL loading looks like this:

```
GL.TexImage2D(All.Texture2D, 0, (int)All.Rgba, Width, Height, 0, (int)All.Rgba, All.UnsignedShort4444, image.GetData());
```

Image Data:

- Size: 16402 Bytes
- Width: 139px
- Height: 59px

#### Edit

The texture is npot but this should be supported by OpenGL ES 2.0.

#### Edit II

It seems i have 2 issues here, the first is that the channels are not correct, the second that the texture is skewed. The skewing may be a issue with NPOT textures and apple because i tested the another image which has a size of 128x128 and it is not skewed but it has some channels swapped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you setup pixel alignment by calling *glPixelStore*?

By default, each row shall be aligned to 4 byte boundary.

The alignment parameter (GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT) does not depends on texture internasl format, but it depends on the source data.
Call *glPixelStore* before calling *TexImage*. Set the parameter to 1, and then study about the pixel transfer parameters!

Comment: No, what do i have to set for the RGBA4 pixel format? Of course the texturing works with RGB565 which is 16bit too.

Comment: The internal format is not considered: width and source format are meaninfull.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice 4444 is the source format! 139 * 2 = 278 ... 278 % 4 != 0

Comment: Setting both, GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT and GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT to 1 helps. Thanks.

Comment: Only PACK should be necessary: UNPACK control pixel transfers from GPU to CPU. Since you are uploading a texture, it's sufficient to set only the UNPACK parameter. Moreover, giver your source format and source extents, a value opf two shall work.

Comment: @Luca could you please explain a little bit your calculation `139 * 2 = 278 ... 278 % 4 != 0`. Is this universal formula to calculate alignment like `width * 2 % 4`?

Comment: @Luca also about `UNPACK control pixel transfers from GPU to CPU` are you sure? from opengl.org: [`unpack operation means write to OpenGL memory`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_transfer_parameters)